# Any way to get test ether from rinkedby without downloading an entire node?

Tags: ether, nodes, testing, rinkeby

I'm trying to learn about smart contracts.  As part of a tutorial I was told to use the "rinkeby" network so I could get some test ether.  Using this tutorial -- https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc, I was told to run

```
geth --rinkeby
```

Although I had over 100GB free space on my Mac OS X machine, I quickly ran out of space and still hadn't synced fully with the node.  Is there an easier way to connect to the rinkeby network without downloading a full node on my machine?  All I want to do is learn about creating a smart contract by running a demo on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Ether on the Rinkeby testnet, just go to http://faucet.rinkeby.io/

You need to make a public post on a social media site with just the address you want Ether sent to, then you paste a link to that post into the site above, and say how much Ether you need.

The reason for the run-around with the social media stuff is to prevent people from getting too much Ether and using it to spam attack the testnet.

Comment: Yeah I tried taht using -- https://twitter.com/laredotornado/status/1006271857027354626 but got teh error "No etherum address found to fund." when I pasted that link into the link you lsited above.

Comment: try posting again as
0x3a58f5f1c5cdb93bb557ec8a472409847d4f4344, that's how addresses are generally formatted, with 0x at the start.

Comment: Good call.  That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a light client like [Metamask](http://metamask.io/) to create an account and interact with the test network.

There is basically an end to end tutorial on how to do this (with Ropsten) here:
[Mastering Ethereum: Ethereum Basics](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/intro.asciidoc)

The same steps should be easy to reproduce on Rinkeby.

Comment: Upvote for the excellent tutorial link.